# How to render Tiff format files in html using angular8

Tags: angular, file-upload

i have a upload section in my application, but here except tiff format files, it is working fine with png,jpeg and other image formats, but not with the tiff format. Here i am not able to show as preview after the file has been choosed.
Can anyone help me to make it work.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-ejpdnw?file=app/app.component.ts)

TS:

```
onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); 
      reader.onload = (event) => { 
        this.url = event.target.result;
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input class="sr-only" id="changePicture" type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)"
                                    accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/bmp,image/tiff,image/eps,image/jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master

**In JS, you can do this:**

```
var fileTypes = ['tiff', 'tif'];

if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
      var fr = new FileReader();
      var extension = files[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
      fr.onload = function(e) {
        success = fileTypes.indexOf(extension) > -1;
        if (success) {
          //Using tiff.min.js library - https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master
          console.debug("Parsing TIFF image...");
          //initialize with 100MB for large files
          Tiff.initialize({
            TOTAL_MEMORY: 100000000
          });
          var tiff = new Tiff({
            buffer: e.target.result
          });
          var tiffCanvas = tiff.toCanvas();
          $(tiffCanvas).css({
            "max-width": "100px",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "display": "block",
            "padding-top": "10px"
          }).addClass("preview");
          $(parentEl).append(tiffCanvas);
        }

      }
      fr.onloadend = function(e) {
        console.debug("Load End");
      }
      fr.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
 }
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/o7j0segKRpjJHwhh8WGO?p=preview&preview

**In Angular (I didn't test it) you can do the follow**

1. Download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seikichi/tiff.js/master/tiff.min.js
   save on **yourproject\src\assets\js\tiff.min.js**
2. Add on file
   angular.json > projects > yourproject > architect > build > options

   **"scripts": ["src/assets/js/tiff.min.js"]**
3. Declare Tiff variable.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    declare var Tiff: any;
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
      title = 'angular-image-viewer';
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadimage();
      }
    
     loadimage(){
    
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.open('GET', '../assets/images/1.TIF');
      xhr.onload = (e) => {
      const tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
      const canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
      document.body.append(canvas); // beautify!
    };
      xhr.send();
     }
    
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You will not be able to directly load tiff file format in html. You have to convert tiff format to jpg/png. You can use tiff.js to acheive this.

Download `tiff.min.js` file and keep it in assets folder. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seikichi/tiff.js/master/tiff.min.js

Register this file in `angular.json`

scripts: `["./src/assets/js/tiff/tiff.min.js"]`

Use this code snippet to convert base64 of tiff format to jpg format.

```js
base64Data?.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
const binaryData = Uint8Array.from(atob(base64Data), c => c.charCodeAt(0)); const tiff = new Tiff({buffer: binaryData}); 
const canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
const jpgBase64Data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, "");
const finalBase64Data="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+jpgBase64Data;
console.log(finalBase64Data);
```